# PHP $_GET['word'] not working when word is a string starting with the '#' character

Tags: php, get

I am using google visualization api to make a plot and then using event handling to get back some information when the plot is clicked on.

When I click on the item, I open a new window with the following url which is supposed to show results from a script called articles.php

`http://..../articles.php?word=nature&datetime=11-4-2011-8`

articles.php starts with

```
$word = $_GET['word'];
$datetime = $_GET['datetime'];
```

When I use var_dump for debugging as follows:

```
var_dump($word);
var_dump($datetime);
```

I get `string(6) "nature" string(11) "11-4-2011-8"`, and the rest of the script works.

However, the problem I am having is that if the word is of the following format:

`word = "#someword"`

then I still see the following url

`http://...../articles.php?word=#nature&datetime=11-7-2011-5`

but the script in articles.php doesn't work. On using

```
var_dump($word);
var_dump($datetime);
```

I see the following:

```
string(0) "" NULL
```

I don't understand why `$_GET['word']` and `$_GET['datetime]` no longer work to grab the word and date transmitted in the URL when the word contains "#" as the first character. Any pointers on what is going on and how I might fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: by default, # marks the fragment part of the url which is not part of the query string (?)

Comment: everything after # ( # included ) will never be sent to your server. It's a browser thing afaik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `#` symbol to be used as a value of a get parameter, it must be URL encoded. The `#` symbol is used in URLs to represent a named anchor or ID in your document and is not parsed into the `_GET` array.

Answer (score 2):

The `#` character denotes the beginning of the [URL fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). This data will not be decoded in the same way as a normal `$_GET` parameter, if it is sent to the server at all.

A literal `#` in a URL must be encoded as `%23` in order to work correctly. So you URL would be `http://...../articles.php?word=%23nature&datetime=11-7-2011-5`. Then `var_dump($word);` will show `string(7) "#nature"`